# "Cannot find Table[0]" - Only in production?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

Some code on our production server is suddenly giving us some trouble. Production has not been changed in about a year, and I've confirmed that the database has not changed either.

If I run the same code on my machine (Yay Source Control!), I do not get the error that appears in production and everything works fine. I'll post the code below, but there has to be something else going on.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if there is no *Table[0]*, that means my query isn't returning any data. Yet, running the same query directly through SQL Management Studio gives me the data I want.

```
    var ds = GetData(queryString);
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        var ddlDataSet = GetAdds();
    }
    private List<tAdd> GetAdds()
    {
        var ds = GetData(queryString);
        var aList = new tAdd[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];//THIS IS WHERE ERROR HITS
        //Do other stuff
        ...
    }

    private DataSet GetData(string queryString)
    {
        var connectionString =
              ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;

        var ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

            adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorPanel.Visible = true;
            ErrorPanel.Enabled = true;
            SearchPanel.Enabled = false;

            const string NotificationsEmail = "mailto:emailguy@email.com";
            ErrorAlertLabel.Text =
                "An err happened. " +
                "Please contact the people who do stuff ";
            ErrorAlertLabel.Visible = true;
            ErrorMessageLiteral.Text = "<br />" + "<br />" +
                                       "Message: " + ex.Message + "<br />" +
                                       "StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "<br />" +
                                       "Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "<br />" +
                                       "Full Detals: " + ex + "<br />";
            ErrorMessageLiteral.Visible = true;
        }

        return ds;
     }
```

I may just try republishing the same version again, but who knows if that will fix it. If anyone needs more info please let me know and thank you in advance.

**Actual Error Text:** "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0."

Comment: Has the connection string changed?  Permissions in the database relating to that user?  If using Windows Authentication, has the user running the AppPool been changed?

Comment: The connection string hasn't changed, nor permissions. I've confirmed this with the DBAs & I use the same connection string when running the code on my PC (which works). Thank you!

Comment: Whats the *actual* error? "Cannot find table[0]" doesn't sound like a .NET exception.

Comment: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0." I'll add to OP as well.

Comment: In GetData's `//Do Error stuff`, are you rethrowing the exception? what actuall 'do stuff' do you have there?

Comment: Are the two usages of the queryString the same and if so does it consume the data in the act of reading?

Comment: It's supposed to make a custom error panel visible & enabled, but it's not supposed to actually throw an exception. When the exception occurs, though, I'm just brought to the standard .NET error screen.

Comment: The queryStrings are the same query under the conditions in which I'm testing them. I'm not sure what you mean by consume.

Comment: what about the .config entry are they pointing to the production database in production..? also is there a way that you can confirm that the build / deployment of the updated code is in production..?
also without any code in your catch block it's like taking a shot in the dark

Comment: are you sure this line doesn't error out in your when you test locally `var aList = new tAdd[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];`what is `tadd` why not just change that to var recCount =ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;`

Comment: .config points the same way in all versions for this DB. It's read only, so we didn't need a test version. The version in production has been there for a year and has worked until today. There is some code in the catch block, just nothing relevant. Thank you for your help!

Comment: tAdd[] is an array containing a custom class: tAdd. That line is setting the array length.

Comment: ok then what happens when you hover over this line ` adapter.Fill(ds);` in the quickwatch does ds show any rows..? if so then the error is in this line `var aList = new tAdd[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];//THIS IS WHERE ERROR HITS` which looks rather strange to me

Comment: If it's read only, try pointing your local app to the production DB. Then you can apply break points and step through it with the debugger.

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I don't get an error when I run the exact same code on my machine and debug it. adapter.Fill(ds) shows 490 rows, which is correct.

Comment: @mxmissile - I've done this as well, no errors :-/

Comment: [deleted, duplicate entry]

Comment: ok so that part works which means that the next line in the return code is wrong which is the var aList what does tAdd look like can you show that code.. if that's the case refactor the code to return the dataset then check the count.. why's the array[] used for

Comment: does your deployment use .dll's or do you have the actual .cs files being deployed..? there has to be a difference in the source code to the target then or something in the database environment Permissions or something has changed ...

Comment: I can't go into specifics on tAdd, but it's a pretty ordinary class. It has name, id, and user properties. Nothing fancy. I need to display a list of tAdds, hence the array. This code is actually part of search functionality.

Comment: was it always working.. if so I will not push the issue.. but it would help to see what the class looks like otherwise like I've mentioned ...it's like having us shoot in the dark and expecting one of us to hit the target

Comment: Always working, and still working except from the server. I've felt like pulling out my hair all day, lol. I've tried to include all of the relevant code to avoid clutter, but everything that leads to the point where the error hits (marked above with a comment) is included

Comment: I have a feeling the clue you need is going to be in that `//Do error stuff`, specifically the `InnerException` of the `Exception` that is caught.

Comment: @mxmissile - I added everything back to the Catch if that helps?

Comment: So just to confirm, your `ErrorMessageLiteral` is NOT displayed when you get the `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: @mxmissile correct. I just get the standard .NET error page: "Server error in "/AppName" Application"

Answer (score 1):

I think you still have a flaw in your error handling that got exposed.

In `GetData`, you catch any `Exception` that occurs and set a bunch of UI elements to Visible and populate them with information, but you *don't stop the process from continuing*.  `GetData` just continues on after the `catch` block, and returns an empty `DataSet`.  `GetAdds` is oblivious to the fact that an error occured, tries to access a table in the `DataSet` that doesn't exist, and throws *another* exception that is not handled by your code, but is instead handled by ASP.NET, which throws away all of your error information and just shows a generic error page.

I would not use such detailed error handling within a low-level method, but add more global error handling.  Since you don't add any meaningful information to the exception, I would just let it bubble up and handle it at the application level.

If you want to add more information to a low-level exception, throw a *new* exception with more detail, and assign the original exception to the new exception's `InnerException` property.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have any pdb files in production , if you dont have them than go to your project right click on properties under Build  -> Advanced -> debug info -> pdb build this and please run it production,

If you have these than you can get the exact line where it is breaking.

This might occure,if there is a dead lock on the tables on production. or the permissions are missing.

Comment: I don't have permissions to publish, so the process will take at least a day :(. However, Production, Test, and my machine all point to the same DB. My application only reads that particular DB, so we had no need for a test, dev, or QA version of the database. And everything has been working everywhere else.

Comment: what changes did you make.. it's really hard to determine anything when you have left out some pertinent code especially the part you mentioned about the array[]

Comment: No changes have been made. This code has worked fine for a year.

Comment: ok any environment changes for example compiling the project from .net 2.0 to 3.5 / 4.0 or 4.5 can you do a clean on the project and rebuild all...?

Comment: This  is more related to the Db, can you ask your dba to check whether if there is any deadlock on that table and also is this a webserver or an app server

Comment: @DJKRAZE - no environment changes. I haven't done any, and I would have been notified if someone else did. I will confirm this though.

Comment: @JordanBelfort - I told the DBA about the issue and he said nothing was changed, but I will ask specifically about a deadlock. And it is on a webserver

Comment: sounds like a DB issue on the Production I highly doubt that you are referencing the same production database in your Dev/Test environment.. if so then I would recommend your DBA make some serious changes

Comment: We definitely are. I'm not a DB guy, so I don't know why they chose to do that. But that's the only DB in my code that only has the one connection string.

Comment: the database in production, will have some memory issues sometimes which might cause all these , its always better if there is a DBA who is checking all the deadlocks and clearing them whenever occured

Comment: @JordanBelfort - I hope your right. The thing that bugs me is that it's working from my machine and it's working from our test server. They all use the same permissions, so I would think a deadlock would affect all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working today. I finally got a-hold of our Web Admin and asked him to restart the web server - this after I'd confirmed that my code and the DB were not the problem.

As soon as the web server booted back up everything was working fine. There are quite a few applications running on the server, so it may have been something getting tangled up.